# 2d Char array display in grid

Tags: arrays, char, 2d

I am having difficulties initializing 2d char arrays. When it does work, it gives me a hexa output. I am looking for something along the lines of grid.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


main() 
{   


//char test[5][5] = {'***\0','***\0','***\0','***\0','***\0'};
char test[5][5] = {"***\0","***\0","***\0","***\0","***\0"};
cout << test << endl;
cout << char[2][2] << endl;


cin.get();
return 0;


}
```

String array was suggested but I need defined array addresses for another array that tie it to a price.

Comment: You can't initlialize 2d arrays liks this.  What you're really doing is trying to initialize test[5][5] with an array of char*.  Initialize in loops, I'll post some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        test[i][j] = '*';
    }
}

//Alternatively you can go for this

char test[5][5] = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 
                   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 
                   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 
                   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 
                   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};
```

This obviously won't net you precisely what you want, it will need some tweaking.  This will get you a two d array of chars, all set to '*'.  It is probably better though to use std::vector or std::array, but this will function at least.

I consider the second method kind of "dangerous" as it's taking advantage of the fact that in memory test[25] == test[5][5], but you should be clear to use whichever you like better.